# error al mostrar opciones de un select en laravel y vue js

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

no muestra nada en el option pero en la consola si puedo ver los datos

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#aplicacion',
    data: {
        departamento:'',
        municipios:[],
      },
      methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
            var id = event.target.value;
            var url = 'https://localhost/todojuegos/todojuegos/public/municipio/'+id;
            axios.get(url)
              .then(function (response) {
                this.municipios = response.data;
                console.log(this.municipios);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
      },
});
```

HTML

```
 <select id="Municipio" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('Municipio') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
                                    <option v-for="muni in municipios">
                                    @{{ muni.municipio }}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
```

Comment: tus vistas las tienes con la extensión blade? me causa duda por el símbolo de arroba que veo en la impresión del valor

Comment: si estan en blade

Comment: dentro del option deberías tener un value y ahí imprimir el valor

Comment: si comprendo pero en @{{ muni.municipio }} debería aparecer el nombre del municipio y no sale nada  no se si me falta algo en el método para hacer que renderize

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de la etiqueta de agrupamiento option, debes tener una option que es la o las que van a listar los valores que te esten llegando; del modo siguiente

```
 <select v-for="muni in municipios">
    <option value="">@{{ muni.municipio }}</option>
  </select>
```

Importante.

Dentro del option, tienes un atributo llamado value, ahí vas a mandar por ejemplo el id, de tu registro para que cuando el usuario vea tu select, el elija el nombre del municipio pero el sistema en el value toma el id del municipio elegido, mas o menos así mira

```
 <select v-for="muni in municipios">
    <option value="@{{ muni.id }}">@{{ muni.municipio }}</option>
  </select>
```

> Claro esta verifica el nombre de tus claves que estan llegando pero
>   esto te debería servir como guía

Comment: la claves estan correctas esta es mi respuesta `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{id_municipio: 1, municipio: "Leticia", departamento_id_departamento: 1}
1
:
{id_municipio: 2, municipio: "Puerto Nariño", departamento_id_departamento: 1}
length`
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: los datos vienen cargados desde php la cuestión es que digamos yo cambio el select departamento el me trae según el departamento los municipios esos municipios que vienen de la base de datos los paso a la data municipio pero nunca se muestran

Answer (score 1):

El error fue solucionado el motivo era por colocar el function acá

```
.then(function (response) {}
```

en su lugar coloque

```
.then(response => {

          }
```

y funciono actualizo la variable municipio

Comment: que genial encontraste la respuesta solo te dejo la mía como apoyo si en algo te sirve @Andersson Meza Andrade